# Por que variavel tem mesmo valor para instâncias diferentes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, node.js, api

Tenho o seguinte código

Arquivo 1 :

```
var fbuser_firstName;
var FB = require('fb');

var User = function (sender) {
    FB.api('/' + sender, 'get', {access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}, function (response) {
       User.initFbProfileInfo(response.first_name,response.locale);
     });
};

User.initFbProfileInfo = function (first_name,locale) {
   fbuser_firstName = first_name;
   fbuser_locale = locale;
};

User.prototype.getFb_firstName = function () {
    return fbuser_firstName;
};

module.exports = User;
```

Arquivo 2 :

```
for(//quantidade){
    user_profile = new User();
      user_profile.getFb_firstName(sender)
}
```

onde sender e uma identificacao do usuario. a variavel fbuser_firstName deveria receber o nome do usuario atual. O problema, é que quando tem 2 usuarios ao mesmo tempo, os 2 recebem o mesmo nome. Por exemplo se o usuarioA falar, o usuarioB vai ter o nome do usuarioA tambem. Como posso resolver isso? ( tem  relaçao com o escopo da variavel? )